# The faster you walk

Tags: situation, paradox

The faster you walk, the quicker you'll get there, it's true.  But be warned, it's not without a price, for the faster you go, the further you'll have to walk before you arrive.

Comment: Does this has anything to do with the space-time relativity paradox?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This could work:

> You're meeting a friend walking towards you *(replace friend by anything that travels in your direction : bus, train etc...)*. The faster you go, the further you'll meet him, albeit quicker.

Alternatively (with the same reasoning):

> You're walking on a conveying belt.

Comment: You're on the right track, but it's not the scenario that prompted this riddle.

Comment: The first scenario perfectly fits every part of the puzzle. If it isn’t acceptable as an answer, the question may be overly broad.

Comment: Accepting the second solution.  This notion came to me while I was on a moving walkway at the airport.

Answer (score 1):

Could your destination be...

> a new year/new day?

If you walk faster...

> towards the East, you will technically see the sun rise sooner on a new day/year/arbitrary increment of time. However, the faster you walk the more distance you will cover before it reaches that time.